# "errors": [ { "detail": "Cannot read property '0' of undefined" how do I get to solve?

Tags: python, undefined

This is the source code is below. with this below I am trying to update my spreadsheet

```
   import requests
   from datetime import datetime
   APP_ID = "mycode"
   API_KEY = "mykey"
   exercise_text = input("Tell me which exercises you did: ")
   
   
   GENDER = "Male"   
   WEIGHT_KG= "68"
   HEIGHT_CM = "168"
   AGE = "36"
   exercise_endpoint = "https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/natural/exercise"
   sheety_endpoint = "https://api.sheety.co/*******/nutritionIx/sheet1"
   
   nutrition_web_config = {
    "query": exercise_text,
    "gender": GENDER,
    "weight_kg": WEIGHT_KG,
    "height_cm": HEIGHT_CM,
    "age": AGE}
   nutrition_headers = {
    'x-app-id':APP_ID,
    'x-app-key': API_KEY,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }


   exercise_response = requests.post(url=exercise_endpoint, json=nutrition_web_config, headers=nutrition_headers, )

   print(exercise_response.raise_for_status())
   print(exercise_response.text)
   print(exercise_response.json())
   ################### Start of Step 4 Solution ######################

   bearer_headers = {
   "Authorization": "Bearer ot"
   }
   sheety_result = exercise_response.json()
   today_date = datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
   now_time = datetime.now().strftime("%X")
   
   for exercise in sheety_result["exercises"]:
       sheet_inputs = {
           "sheet1": {
               "date": today_date,
               "time": now_time,
               "exercise": exercise["name"].title(),
               "duration": exercise["duration_min"],
               "calories": exercise["nf_calories"]
           }
          }
       sheet_response = requests.post(sheety_endpoint, json=sheet_inputs, headers=bearer_headers)
       print(sheet_response.text)
```

I am trying to link and update my google spreadsheet however output is not what I expected
Output:

```
Tell me which exercises you did: run 20minutes
None
{"exercises":[{"tag_id":317,"user_input":"run","duration_min":20,"met":9.8,"nf_calories":222.13,"photo":{"highres":"https://d2xdmhkmkbyw75.cloudfront.net/exercise/317_highres.jpg","thumb":"https://d2xdmhkmkbyw75.cloudfront.net/exercise/317_thumb.jpg","is_user_uploaded":false},"compendium_code":12050,"name":"running","description":null,"benefits":null}]}
{'exercises': [{'tag_id': 317, 'user_input': 'run', 'duration_min': 20, 'met': 9.8, 'nf_calories': 222.13, 'photo': {'highres': 'https://d2xdmhkmkbyw75.cloudfront.net/exercise/317_highres.jpg', 'thumb': 'https://d2xdmhkmkbyw75.cloudfront.net/exercise/317_thumb.jpg', 'is_user_uploaded': False}, 'compendium_code': 12050, 'name': 'running', 'description': None, 'benefits': None}]}
{
 "errors": [
    {
      "detail": "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"
    }
  ]
}
```

how is this possible way to solve this kind of problem?
expected output is not what i expected

Comment: It's possible to solve this by not trying to read the property '0' of 'undefined', or by not using third-party code that tries to do that.

Comment: you may not be creating the json properly. I would suggest doing a `json.dumps(sheet_inputs)`

Comment: can you be more specific, please?

Comment: @mkrieger1 please be more specific

Comment: I don't know how to be more specific. Maybe it would be easier if you created a [mre].

Comment: The error comes from sheety api, which really means you'd have to contact their support to understand the error. Otherwise, the documentation isn't very descriptive... But it gives an example of uploading to "emails" (plural) sheet where "email" (singular) is the nested json key... Just a guess, but switching to exercises / exercise would be better than just "sheet1" in both places